# Where to put a cable tie on an electrical cord?

Tags: electrical, cables, cord-and-plug

When it comes to adding an attached cable wrap to a electrical power cord, is there a proper end to place a cable tie?

Female end? Male end?

I know I can add a wrap to an electrical cord on either end or even place a tie in the center. I am wondering if there is a proper end people prefer. I can't seem to find an answer and I'm about to wrap lots of electrical cords.

[image: cable tie on female end]

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based. It's a matter of personal preference and the use case.

Comment: No, it's a practical use question. I remember what is the correct way with an XLR, I just wanted to figure out if there is a proper way for two-wire and three-wire.

Comment: The answer courtesy of grips who roll out power cables all the time is place the tie on the female end.

Comment: But as a carpenter I'd want them at the male end so they aren't flopping around all day in my work station. Again, subjective.

Answer (score 1):

### How do you unfurl electrical cables?

Unwinding a lot of extension cords; I usually start at the socket, plug in the "plug end" of the cable, and unfurl from there.   Otherwise I have no idea where to start.

Generally unfurling a cable flows best when you do it in reverse: start unfurling from the end you finished furling.   Otherwise it tends to tangle.

So that says start furling at the socket end, and that's where the cable wrap should go.  Also if you don't need the full length, you can use the wrap to re-bind the part of the cable you haven't unfurled.